# Slow counts finally solved

Tags: phoenix-framework, ecto

tl;dr:  `|> Repo.aggregate(:count, :id)` is slow, do use `|> Repo.aggregate(:count)`

I'm running a podcast database with > 5 million episodes. After storing a new episode, I count the episodes for a given podcast for a counter cache like this:

```
episodes_count = where(Episode, podcast_id: ^podcast_id)
                 |> Repo.aggregate(:count, :id)
```

This turned out to get slower and slower. So I started to dig deeper, and I realized, that
in Postgres 12 only `SELECT COUNT(*)` does an index only scan, while `SELECT COUNT(e0.id)` doesn't.

For a cold database (just restarted) even the first index scan is reasonably fast:

```
postgres=# \c pan_prod
Sie sind jetzt verbunden mit der Datenbank »pan_prod« als Benutzer »postgres«.
pan_prod=# EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT count(*) FROM "episodes" AS e0 WHERE (e0."podcast_id" = 35202);
                                                                         QUERY PLAN                                                                          
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Aggregate  (cost=348.51..348.52 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=15.823..15.823 rows=1 loops=1)
   ->  Index Only Scan using episodes_podcast_id_index on episodes e0  (cost=0.43..323.00 rows=10204 width=0) (actual time=1.331..14.832 rows=10613 loops=1)
         Index Cond: (podcast_id = 35202)
         Heap Fetches: 0
 Planning Time: 2.994 ms
 Execution Time: 16.017 ms
```

It even gets faster for the second scan:

```
pan_prod=# EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT count(*) FROM "episodes" AS e0 WHERE (e0."podcast_id" = 35202);
                                                                         QUERY PLAN                                                                         
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Aggregate  (cost=348.51..348.52 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=5.007..5.008 rows=1 loops=1)
   ->  Index Only Scan using episodes_podcast_id_index on episodes e0  (cost=0.43..323.00 rows=10204 width=0) (actual time=0.042..3.548 rows=10613 loops=1)
         Index Cond: (podcast_id = 35202)
         Heap Fetches: 0
 Planning Time: 0.304 ms
 Execution Time: 5.074 ms
```

While the first bitmap heap scan ist terribly slow:

```
pan_prod=# EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT count(e0.id) FROM "episodes" AS e0 WHERE (e0."podcast_id" = 35202);
                                                                    QUERY PLAN                                                                    
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Aggregate  (cost=37181.71..37181.72 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=4098.525..4098.526 rows=1 loops=1)
   ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on episodes e0  (cost=219.51..37156.20 rows=10204 width=4) (actual time=6.508..4082.558 rows=10613 loops=1)
         Recheck Cond: (podcast_id = 35202)
         Heap Blocks: exact=6516
         ->  Bitmap Index Scan on episodes_podcast_id_index  (cost=0.00..216.96 rows=10204 width=0) (actual time=3.657..3.658 rows=10613 loops=1)
               Index Cond: (podcast_id = 35202)
 Planning Time: 0.412 ms
 Execution Time: 4098.719 ms
```

The second one is typically faster:

```
pan_prod=# EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT count(e0.id) FROM "episodes" AS e0 WHERE (e0."podcast_id" = 35202);
                                                                    QUERY PLAN                                                                    
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Aggregate  (cost=37181.71..37181.72 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=18.857..18.857 rows=1 loops=1)
   ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on episodes e0  (cost=219.51..37156.20 rows=10204 width=4) (actual time=6.047..17.152 rows=10613 loops=1)
         Recheck Cond: (podcast_id = 35202)
         Heap Blocks: exact=6516
         ->  Bitmap Index Scan on episodes_podcast_id_index  (cost=0.00..216.96 rows=10204 width=0) (actual time=3.738..3.738 rows=10613 loops=1)
               Index Cond: (podcast_id = 35202)
 Planning Time: 0.322 ms
 Execution Time: 18.999 ms
```

I don't get, why `SELECT count(e0.id)` doesn't use the index, and I would like to know why.
I always thought, I should prefer it, as only one column is looked at, but that is not the case, it seems.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stackoverflow! Very nice that you found the solution yourself :) You can submit the solution to your problem as an answer yourself and mark that as "accepted" so the question will be marked as solved and replied to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I don't get, why SELECT count(e0.id) doesn't use the index, and I would like to know why. I always thought, I should prefer it, as only one column is looked at, but that is not the case, it seems.

It **does** use the index `episodes_podcast_id_index` both times.

Once it can do without additionally looking in the table, the other time it does look into the table.

You didn't provide the index defintion, but it seems like `id` is not part of it. I would also supect that it is not a `not null`able column (it might contains `null` values). Thus, the DB has to fetch the `id` column to see if it is `null`.

Why?

Because `count(*)` counts rows while `count(<expression>)` counts not-null values.

See: https://modern-sql.com/concept/null#aggregates

Comment: Ouch! You are right, I misread the episode_podcast_id index as episode_podcast_id_id index. It's missing the id (compared to my expectations). 
Id is not nullable:

       Spalte       |             Typ             | Sortierfolge | NULL erlaubt? |             Vorgabewert              
 id                 | integer                     |              | not null      | nextval('episodes_id_seq'::regclass)

But I'll fix the index first.